# Nemid Iframe Not Loading in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

We are integrating Nemid Iframe in php. On Our web page Nemid Iframe is not loading, we have checked sp_certificate is correct and param_digest is correct

> Refering Document:
>   https://www.nets.eu/dk-da/kundeservice/nemid-tjenesteudbyder/NemID-tjenesteudbyderpakken/Documents/NemID%20Integration%20-%20OCES.pdf
>
> Refer video Once :
>   https://www.loom.com/share/4469d4144ff4405cb285a67a00b65067
>   Parameters:

```
{
"clientFlow": "Oceslogin2",
"DIGEST_SIGNATURE": "YzYgNTggMzEgNGYgOTYgMmQgNTIgZmIgZjYgMGIgNzggZjcgY2EgZGMgMWUgZDggZGEgYmMgYTMgODQ=",
"ORIGIN": "https://development.brstdev.com",
"PARAMS_DIGEST": "MANqxi+GjplBYVJ1DCkcdMvhxqRYPl2rZquhYT8LZEk=",
"SP_CERT": "",
"TimeStamp": "2019-11-14 13:45:31+0000"
}
```

Iframe url: `https://appletk.danid.dk/launcher/std/1573739173245?time-startup=true`

Ouestions

1. Where we have to find the SP_CERT Keys
2. How to calculate the DIGEST_SIGNATURE
3. From Where we can find the RSA Key

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this one?